# How to execute big SQL files on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have about 50 T-SQL files, some of them are 30MB but some of them are 700MB. I thought on executing them manually, but if the file is bigger than 10MB it throws an out of memory exception on the SQL Server Management Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what _is_ in those 700MB big SQL files?

Comment: I'm curious about that too, though I've seen a collection of INSERT (col1, col2) VALUES('col1 data', 'col2 data'); lines that big.  Like, converting from a different db system or something.

Comment: 50 sql files = U.S states, and each line is an `INSERT` line of a business.

Comment: You may want to break the files in smaller files and load them using one of the sql utilities out there that run files in batch. One of the tools are from redGate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have that much data - wouldn't it be a lot easier and smarter to have that data in e.g. a CSV file and then bulk importing those into SQL Server??

Check out the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command - allows you to quickly and efficiently load large data volumes into SQL Server - much better than such a huge SQL file!

The command looks something like:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.YourTableName
   FROM 'yourfilename.csv'
   WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =';',
          ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n' )
```

or whatever format you might have to import.

Comment: Of course it's more efficient and a better strategy, but sometimes you're given a file of SQL statements.  If you're passing around data between DBMS's, it's possibly the most portable.  So, you can either show some impressive regex-fu and turn it into a csv file, or deal with what you already have.

Answer (score 13):

you can try the sqlcmd command line tool, that may have different memory limits.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Usage example:

```
sqlcmd -U userName -P myPassword -S MYPCNAME\SQLEXPRESS -i myCommands.tsql
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is too obvious, but...did you consider writing a program to loop through the files and call `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` for each line? It's almost trivial.

Less obvious advantages:

- You can monitor the progress of the feed (which is going to take some time)
- You can throttle it (in case you don't want to swamp the server)
- You can add a little error handling in case there are problems in the input files

Comment: +1, this may take a long time, but unless the OP can edit those big files so bulk load will work on them, then this is most likely the only solution.